# Codeigniter autoload library with parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoload, filemaker

I'm using [FX.php](http://www.iviking.org/FX.php/) together with Codeigniter to access a Filemaker DB. Library and config file are autoloaded in config/autoload.php.

This setup works perfectly well on my development machine (OS X, PHP 5.3.14). However, when I run the project on our dev server (Ubuntu Precise, PHP 5.3.10), it doesn't work. There seems to be an issue with the config parameters not being passed to the library. I get the following error messages:

```
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: dataServer
Filename: libraries/CIFX.php
Line Number: 9

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: dataPort
Filename: libraries/CIFX.php
Line Number: 9

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: dataType
Filename: libraries/CIFX.php
Line Number: 9

Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: dataURLType
Filename: libraries/CIFX.php
Line Number: 9
```

My libraries/CIFX.php file looks like this:

```
require('FX.php');

class CIFX extends FX {

    function __construct ($params = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($params['dataServer'], $params['dataPort'], $params['dataType'], $params['dataURLType']);
    }

}
?>
```

My config/CIFX.php file looks like this:

```
$config['dataServer'] = '192.168.1.10';
$config['dataPort'] = '80';
$config['dataType'] = 'FMPro7';
$config['dataURLType'] = '';
$config['dbuser'] = '';
$config['dbpassword'] = '';
```

According to the [Codeigniter manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html), this should be working.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you need to be Passing Parameters When Initializing Your Class

```
$params = array(
    'dataServer' =>  $this->config->item('dataServer');, 
    'dataPort'   =>  $this->config->item('dataPort');
);

$this->load->library('CIFX ', $params);
```

Comment: As I wrote in my original post the library is loaded using CI's autoloading feature. The user manual says the following about this: "You can also pass parameters stored in a config file. Simply create a config file named identically to the class file name and store it in your application/config/ folder." That's what I did and works on my local machine, but not on the dev server.